# "This file came from another computer and may be blocked..."

Tags: windows-7, permissions, properties

Having a constant issue with (what I assume to be) permissions on Windows 7.

I have a certain number of files I need complete access to (actually, Visual Studio needs unrestricted access to - to build my solution)

As you can see in the below screenshot they are 'blocked' because they've been downloaded from the internet.

[image: UNBLOCK THE FILE WINDOWS YOU SUCK.]

My issue is that whenever I click Unblock, Apply & OK, it restricts the file automatically again as soon after. ie I unblock X file, reopen the properties and it needs unblocking again.

**Is there a perma-unblock or am I missing something?**

*I'm aware I can turn the "block downloaded files" feature off in gpedit, but this has not solved my issue*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think is is a weirdo issue dealing with UAC and program files.  Try turing off UAC; go unblock the file; and then turn back on UAC.  I think the problem occurs because the properties window doesn't automatically elevate when doing unblocking.

Alternatively, move the file out of program files to somewhere ordinary like your desktop. Unblock it there, and then move it back.

Try the second way first, since it doesn't involve turning UAC off.

Comment: Second way worked a charm. Crazy stuff. Cheers.

Comment: I had this exact problem and did what Knox suggested with no result. I solved the problem by creating a .zip file from the blocked file and then extracting it.